# why redirect not work in springmvc

Tags: spring-mvc, redirect, response.redirect

I want to redirect after a upload, and want to redirect "files" page. but after submit successfully, the url in browser doesn't redirect, I also use firebug to check if there is any redirect, but not happen. 
I change the "redirect:/files" to "redirect:/files.jsp" also not help.
is there any mistake?

Here is my code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({ "/files", "/files/" })
    public class FileAdminController {

     @RequestMapping(value = { "/upload/index", "/upload", "/upload/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String showUplaod() {
        return "upload";
    }

     @RequestMapping(value = { "/index", "/index/", "/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String showFilePage() {
        return "files";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(
        @RequestParam("jarName") String jarName,
        @RequestParam("manifestName") String manifestName,
        @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile file) {

        try {

             File file1 = new File("c:/uploads/");

             file1.getParentFile().mkdirs();
             file1.createNewFile();
             BufferedOutputStream stream = new
             BufferedOutputStream(
             new FileOutputStream(file1));

             stream.write(bytes);
             stream.close();
            return "redirect:/files";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + jarName + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`redirect:`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix) is a view name which gets resolved by the `UrlBasedViewResolver`. But with [`@ResponseBody`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody) you tell spring that this controller is not returning a view name. I.e. you will have to take care about the redirect by yourself, by injecting the `HttpServletResponse`.

Comment: could you elaborate please because i'm facing this issue and i don't have @ResponseBody in my controller